# How do I dynamically add Buttons to a list of Array ITEMS in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I would like to add remove buttons to an element of an array "lists". The syntax I have should be correct but for some reason isn't working. The buttons will then remove an element when clicked. The Add function is working and items are being displayed in an unordered list, from the array I want to display a remove button beside each member of the array

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do APP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
        <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add Activity" id="event" name="events">
        <button id="add" onclick="Add()">Add</button>
    
            <ul id="sec"> 
                  
            </ul>
        
</body>
<script>
var lists=[];
function Add(){
    var list=document.getElementById("event").value
    var s= lists.includes(list);
    if (s==true){
        alert("Activity already added")
    }else{
        lists.push(list)
        console.log(lists) 
    }
    var output=lists.join('<br/>');
    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML=output;
}
//delete activity from list
function remove(){

}

//Create buttons for items
function createBtn(){
    var sec= document.getElementById('sec')
    for(var i=0; i<lists.length;i++){
        var butn=document.createElement("button");
        butn.innerHTML=lists[i];
        sec.appendChild(butn);
    }
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML=output;` - you should avoid doing this because it invalidates DOM object references. It also opens yourself up to script-injection attacks - it also means your script won't work at all if someone types a `<` character into the input textbox.

Comment: from a quick skim, I see you are not calling your createBtn function, try doing that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to do this, here is one (following what you already have in your code)

```js
var activities = [];

const addActivity = () => {
  var activity = document.getElementById("event").value;

  if (activities.includes(activity)) {
    alert("Activity already added")
  } else {
    activities.push(activity)
    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML += `<li idx="${activities.length-1}">${activity} <button type="button" onclick="deleteActivity()">Delete</button></li>`
  }
}

const deleteActivity = () => {
  const btn = event.target;
  const index = parseInt(btn.parentElement.getAttribute("idx"), 10);
  activities.splice(index, 1);
  document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = activities.map((activity, i) => {
    return `<li idx="${i}">${activity} <button type="button" onclick="deleteActivity()">Delete</button></li>`
  });
}
```

```css
 ul {
   list-style-type: none;
 }
 li {
   margin: 4px;
 }
```

```html
<h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Add Activity" id="event" name="events">
<button id="add" onclick="addActivity()">Add</button>

<ul id="sec">
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm not used to Jquery so I am having some difficulty understanding the parts of the code with the $ signs

Comment: I do not use jquery too

Comment: what does the ${} syntax mean?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation